# Looking for a list with examples of a class names

Tags: naming

Is there any list/source/dictionary with examples of a good class names somewhere over the Internet? I'm not looking for naming conventions, but rather for some resource with names and explanations when is proper to use them. I'm finding it somewhat difficult to came up with good names when I'm naming my classes so something like this will be helpfull:

SomethingBuilder - use in such cases...

SomethingRequest - use in such cases...

Comment: Have a look at wellknown patterns like those of [Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/) or [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_(book)). Your `Builder` might match [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to look for repositories of frameworks or projects. They have plenty of classes with some really good names. Examples are symfony, kohana, cakephp, codeigniter, drupal etc... You can search for them on github to reach their repositories.

I know it is not a straight answer to your question but it still may be of help.